# Is there any way to make class names the same as the CSS custom variable?

Tags: css, global-variables, mixins, css-variables, scss-mixins

I'm looking for any solution that can reduce this CSS redundancy:

```
--root {
  --brown: #775E3E;
  --headline: "Big Shoulders Display", "Oswald", "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.brown {color: var(--brown);}
.brown-bg {background-color: var(--brown);}

.headline {font-family: var(--headline);}
```

The end goal is using `.headline` and `.brown` classes directly in HTML.

```
<h1 class="headline brown">I AM BROWN WITH CUSTOM FONT</h1>
```

Can this be achieved without having to make an exhausting `:root` list of colors and then needing to specify each class name (which would be the same) individually?

Basically I want `--headline = .headline` & `--brown = .brown`

If there is no simple solution in CSS I am open to using SCSS, a SASS mixin or even javascript.
Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SCSS for this. I built a snippet for you. It's self descriptive.

```
// Arrange them in
// varName: (type, value)
$vars: (
  brown: (color, brown),
  headline: (font-family, '"Big Shoulders Display", "Oswald", "Open Sans", sans-serif')
);

// Turn all those variables to CSS Variables
:root {
  @each $var, $val in $vars {
    --#{$var}: #{nth($val, 2)};
  }
}

// Create classes out of those variables
@each $var, $val in $vars {
  .#{$var} {
    #{nth($val, 1)}: var(--#{$var});
  }

  // If type is color then generate a bg color class
  @if nth($val, 1) == color {
    .#{$var}-bg {
      background-color: var(--#{$var});
    }
  }
}
```

Then it will generate CSS like this

```css
:root {
  --brown: brown;
  --headline: "Big Shoulders Display", "Oswald", "Open Sans", sans-serif;
}

.brown {
  color: var(--brown);
}

.brown-bg {
  background-color: var(--brown);
}

.headline {
  font-family: var(--headline);
}
```

This is probably what you're looking for. Happy helping.

Comment: GENIUS! Works even better than I had hoped